# how to avoid blank screen on RUN command

Tags: winapi, visual-foxpro, foxpro, shellexecute

Visula FoxPro 9 application runs application and wait for finish using command

```
RUN openssl.exe  ... parameters
```

multiple times.
This causes ugly blank screen flashing.

How to remove blank screen flash ? how to run application miniized ?
Which is exact replacement of RUN command for this ?
Can shellexecute or Ed Rauh API_APIRun class used or is there other simple solution ?

Comment: the best use `CreateProcess("path\openssl.exe", parameters,...)` with `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag

Comment: Where to find sample VFP code for this? How to wait for process termination ? `RUN /N7` runs minimized but does not wait for process completion

Comment: if you want wait for process termination call `WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE)` where `PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;` after and only if `CreateProcess(.., &pi);` return `true`

Comment: Where to find sample code in VFP which implements this? How to return pi to VFP code ?

Comment: Google maybe ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use API_APPRUN by the late, great Ed Rauh.

You can find the code here:
https://www.universalthread.com/ShowHeaderArticleOneItem.aspx?ID=7789

Below is the basic usage. I created a visual class library (VCX) using Ed's code. I then dropped the class on a vfp form with the name of "apprun".

```
lcCmdLine = "openssl.exe  ... parameters"
thisform.apprun.init(lcCmdLine)
thisform.apprun.LaunchAppAndWait()
```

API_APPRUN is clean and should work as you expect.